# Linker command fail on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

**Background:**

My iOS application runs on the simulator the first 1-3 times succesfully, 4th time and forward, the build fails with the following error. If I close Xcode and run again, it starts working but then this cycle keeps happening

**Question:**

How do I get rid of this error? Restarting every time this error shows up is taking up too much of my time.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Made sure I'm opening the right project(With Pods)
2. Turned Enable Bitcoin - No (In the Build Settings)

**Error**

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vijayraja/Documents/GitHub/SILO/silo-ios/Carthage/Build/iOS'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vijayraja/Documents/GitHub/SILO/silo-ios/SILO/Frameworks'
ld: framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Frameworks]

Comment: In what directory is this GoogleAppMeasurement framework actually located?  Is that directory in your settings' Framework Search Paths?

Comment: Hey, I've added a picture of my frameworks, please check @PhillipMills

Comment: The picture doesn't tell me anything about GoogleAppMeasurement.  That's what the error (and my comment) is about.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix something if you won't give me any useful information.